# Does Angular Dart support ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

AngularJS supports a ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directive to have the ng-repeat repeat with several elements that are siblings. Is there a similar feature in Angular Dart or a different method to accomplish this?

I am trying to loop through a menu object and display it in a Bootstrap dropdown menu. Every time I repeat the `dropdown-header` element I would like the `divider` to appear before it (except the first time, which I will deal with later).

```dart
<div class="btn-group open">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Category 1</li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Category 2</li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a><a></a></li><a>
  </a></ul><a>
</a></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OzzieOrca/aqn3r/)

Here's what I have but I'm not sure what to do with the divider:

```dart
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="menuItem.hasSubPages">
    <li class="divider"></li><!-- not sure what to do with this -->
    <li ng-class="{'dropdown-header': subMenuItem.isCategory}" ng-repeat="subMenuItem in menuItem.subMenuItems" ng-switch="subMenuItem.isCategory">
        <a href="#/{{menuItem.url + '/' + subMenuItem.url}}" ng-switch-when="false">{{subMenuItem.name}}</a>
        <span ng-switch-when="true">{{subMenuItem.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually AngularDart doesn't support the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directives.

As you can see in the [AngularDart API](https://docs.angulardart.org/), no reference is available for this kind of directive.

BUT you can accomplish what you want by encapsulating the elements into a new Component as explained here : [Creating a Custom Component](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/05-ch03-component.html)

Comment: I guess creating a component would work but I feel like creating an entire component with a component class and an HTML template with only 3 lines in it seems like overkill and not very clean.

Comment: It's can be see like overused, in a other case you can simply put a `<span></span>` balise around you `<ul></ul>` or `<li></li>` balise and do the `ng-repeat` on the span

Comment: Hmm. I thought that would be a good idea at first but I just realized that putting a span around `<li class="divider"></li><li class="dropdown-header">Category 2</li><li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>` messes up the styling for Item 3. I don't really want to have to fix the Bootstrap CSS...

Comment: Ok, so the component stay the best advice i can give to you

Comment: Maybe I don't understand components well enough. but if I create a `menuItem` component and put it on the page using `<menu-item></menu-item>` that element will be added to the DOM and will break the CSS where `<li>` needs to be a direct child of `<ul>` but now there is a `<menu-item>` in between right? Is there any way to have it replace the element?

Comment: I guess one other way I've been thinking about accomplishing this is using `ng-template` and then `ng-include` but this has the same issue as creating a component because a new element is created. Is there any way to have `ng-include` or components replace the element they are called from?